# SQL Cross apply to rotate the comma separated values

Tags: sql, sql-server, csv

```
declare @RuleTable table (RuleId int, Pattern varchar(max) , Frequency int )


insert into @RuleTable 
select 1, '3,5,4,6' , 2

 SELECT 
 ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY items ORDER BY (select 1)) - 1  AS Id,
 RuleId,
 items AS ShiftId 
FROM @RuleTable
    CROSS APPLY SplitNew(REPLICATE(REPLACE(','+ LTRIM(RTRIM(Pattern)) +',',',0,',',') +',', Frequency ), ',') as ss
```

current output is this...

[image]

but in expected output I should not lost the order of the comma separated string

Means Output should be like

```
ShiftId 
3
3
5
5
4
4
6
6
```

Note: Frequency means how many times each shiftid from comma separated string should repeat.

Comment: What is `SplitNew`? That isn't a built in TVF (and I suspect is the problem, as it doesn't consider ordinal position). You query, however, contains no `ORDER BY` so the rows can be in what ever arbitrary order SQL Server wants to return them in. If you want the rows in a specific order, you need to include an `ORDER BY`

Comment: Note that your clause `ORDER BY (SELECT 1)` is meaningless, this might as well mean "Put the rows in any arbitrary order", and every row in the partition will have the same value, therefore can all equally have a chance to appear at the start, end or middle of the group.

Answer (score 2):

It appears you have a couple of problems here. Firstly, I would guess that your splitter (that we are missing the definition of) does not observe/retain ordinal position. Therefore we need to use a splitter than does. I recommend [`delimitedsplit8k_LEAD`](https://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/reaping-the-benefits-of-the-window-functions-in-t-sql-2).

Then we need to look at how you repeat the rows. Using `REPLICATE` like that isn't the right approach. You'll be better off with a Tally. I've used an inline one here, and assume `Frequency` can't have a value greater than `10`. If it does, use a CTE to create an inline Tally (there are plenty of examples out there on how to do this, and **don't** use the ones that use an rCTE, because they are **slow**).

After that, you end up with something like this:

```sql
SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY DS.Item ORDER BY DS.ItemNumber) - 1 AS ID,
       RT.RuleId,
       DS.Item
FROM @RuleTable RT
     CROSS APPLY dbo.DelimitedSplit8K_LEAD(RT.Pattern,',') DS
     JOIN (VALUES(1),(2),(3),(4),(5),(6),(7),(8),(9),(10))V(I) ON RT.Frequency >= V.I 
ORDER BY DS.ItemNumber,
         V.I;
```

Comment: just wanted to understand that why do we need 

JOIN (VALUES(1),(2),(3),(4),(5),(6),(7),(8),(9),(10))V(I)


? what it does and why we are using V ?

Comment: From my answer, @vijaysahu: *"Then we need to look at how you repeat the rows. Using `REPLICATE` like that isn't the right approach. You'll be better off with a Tally. I've used an inline one here"* Without the tally, you would get 1 row per item, not 2.

Comment: As for why `V`, "V" for "**V**alues"; basic aliasing. Same reason it's "RT" for **R**ule**T**able and "DS" for **D**elimited**S**plit8k_LEAD".

Answer (score 1):

You can find the *first* position of a value in the string:

```
SELECT ss.seqnum - 1  AS Id, RuleId, items AS ShiftId 
FROM @RuleTable CROSS APPLY
     (SELECT ss.*,
             ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY CHARINDEX(',' + Frequency + ',', ',' + Pattern + ',')) as seqnum
      FROM SplitNew(REPLICATE(REPLACE(','+ LTRIM(RTRIM(Pattern)) +',', ',0,', ',') +',', Frequency ), ',') as ss
     ) ss;
```

I don't understand your search -- but then you are using an undocumented function.  This would more typically be written as:

```
SELECT (ss.seqnum - 1) as Id, rt.RuleId, ss.value as ShiftId 
FROM @RuleTable rt CROSS APPLY
     (SELECT ss.*,
             ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY CHARINDEX(',' + rt.Frequency + ',', ',' + rt.Pattern + ',')) as seqnum
      FROM string_split(pattern, ',') ss
     ) ss;
```

Note that this uses the built-in [`string_split()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/string-split-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) function.  There is no need for a user-defined function with this method.